# HTML - Responsive Navigation Bar: SCRIPT NOT WORKING

Tags: html, css, menu, media-queries, responsive-navigation

I am following this tutorial **EDIT: changed link to specific time of video** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZsuI5wyRzs&feature=youtu.be&t=560 on how to make a responsive nagivation bar before I dive into the main content.

For some reason at this part of the timeline here (*I saved the link to current time so you can see what I'm talking about without having to skim through the video*) I followed the steps exactly, but my hamburger icon is not being activated when it is clicked in order to bring down the drop-down menu. Other than that, everything else looks pretty good. What is wrong with my code? Please take a look at it below.

Thanks

```css
/*CSS Page*/

/*-----HTML Body-----*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/*----End HTML Body-----*/

/*-----Start of Navigation Bar-----*/

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #8000ff;
}

ul {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

/*For mouse hover*/

ul li:hover {
  background: #4dff4d;
}

/*Smartphone/Tablet: Menu Bar*/

.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #cc66ff;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}

/*-----End of Navigation Bar-----*/

/* Media Queries for Smaller Screen Size Begins */

@media (max-width: 786px) {
    .toggle {
      display: block;
    }

/* Navigation Drop down */

    ul {
      width: 100%;
      display: none;
    }

/* End Navigation Drop Down */

    ul li {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .active {
      display: block;
    }
}


/* Media Queries for Smaller Screen Size Ends */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--HTML Page-->

<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <body>


    <nav>
      <div class="toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-bars menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <script src="https:////code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready() {
        $('menu').click(function() {
          $('ul').toggleClass('active')
        })
      })
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 issues...

1. Missing callback function on the ready event...

   `$(document).ready()`

Need to be this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

2. You're missing the '.' in front of 'menu' class selector...

   `$('menu')`

Needs to be like this...

`$('.menu')`

Working example below...

```css
/*CSS Page*/

/*-----HTML Body-----*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/*----End HTML Body-----*/

/*-----Start of Navigation Bar-----*/

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #8000ff;
}

ul {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

/*For mouse hover*/

ul li:hover {
  background: #4dff4d;
}

/*Smartphone/Tablet: Menu Bar*/

.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #cc66ff;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}

/*-----End of Navigation Bar-----*/

/* Media Queries for Smaller Screen Size Begins */

@media (max-width: 786px) {
    .toggle {
      display: block;
    }

/* Navigation Drop down */

    ul {
      width: 100%;
     /* display: none; */
      display: block;
      height:0px;
      transition: height 0.5s linear;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

/* End Navigation Drop Down */

    ul li {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .active {
      /* display: block; */  
      height: 300px;
    }
}

/* Media Queries for Smaller Screen Size Ends */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--HTML Page-->

<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>

 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> -->
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <body>


    <nav>
      <div class="toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-bars menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <script src="https:////code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menu').click(function() {
          $('ul').toggleClass('active')
        })
      })
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for all the crazy edits. I despise these built-in SO code editors. For longer working examples like this I'd suggest using https://codepen.io, https://codesandbox.io, https://jsfiddle.net .etc and providing a link to working example. Pretty much anything other than StackOverflow's. Sorry, not sorry SO. Love you guys.

Comment: Thanks man! It now works! Now I have one more question. Do you know of an idea of how I can now squeeze in some of the last bit of code to create a smooth transition like this here? https://jsfiddle.net/xg3s83yo/ Make sure you resize the preview panel so that you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: No problem and sure give me one second. I've lost all patience with this god forsaken code editor : /

Comment: Ok done, but its kind of an ugly/brittle implementation with the hard coded `300px` height. I thought you could transition to `height: auto`, but I was mistaken. Plenty of better ways to do this (css transform, or JS animations), but will get the job done for now

Comment: JsFiddle here if you want to play around... https://jsfiddle.net/8wuta74g/

Comment: Thanks man! I'll play around with it until I find the transition I like to fit my taste!